# How to update a list from an imported module once imported?

Tags: python, python-3.x

test.py

```
import threading

a_list = []
def a():
    while True:
        a_list.append("A")

threading.Thread(target=a).start()
```

test1.py

```
import test
from test import a_list
import time

while True:
    print(a_list)
    time.sleep(1)
```

if I import the file "test" and infinitely append "A" into a list and use "test1" to print the values, for some reason the values WILL NOT update for test1

How can I make test1 recognise that the list has been updated from file "test" and print it out using the file "test1"

I rushed this code to share in here, I am sorry about that. Some help would be nice. I tried googling it but I couldn't find anything

Comment: Can you add some details about your Python version to your question? I can't reproduce this on my machine (after adding a `time.sleep(0.2)` to `test.py`, to reduce the overall length of `a_list`).

Comment: It is Python 3.x and when an item is appended to the list inside of test.py I want test1.py to detect the change inside of the imported file and print it out... Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In short: don't do it. It's possible to do but hard to do correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `global` in your function:

```
import threading

 a_list = []
 def a():
      global a_list
      while True:
         a_list.append("A")

 threading.Thread(target=a).start()
```

Althougth I recommend against such code.

Beware: "Here be dragons"